# What Feats for a Hellfire Ur-lock Disciple?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

Looking to make a Warlock, Hellfire Warlock, Binder, Ur-Priest, Eldritch Disciple thing for a new campaign, and I have no clue what to do feat wise as I have never ran a warlock based class before. Final total should be (unless I miscalculate):

**Warlock 4/Binder 1/Ur-Priest 2/Hellfire Warlock 3/Eldritch Disciple 10**

Obviously the Ur-Priest requires Iron Will and Spell Focus so that chews up 2 feats right there. I am not looking to go glaivelock with it and mainly focus on blasting. However fluff wise my character is supposed to have an affinity for dragons so anything there could also work. FYI I am running as a silverbrow human.

We're starting out at level 6, and can use material from any source.  Nonetheless, I don't want anything involving psionics in this character.

Comment: Also, what invocations are you taking?

Comment: Not sure yet? Probably anything that keeps with being ranged, crowd control, maybe some utility?

Comment: Also, has your DM banned strongheart vests from working with hellfire?

Comment: What do you want us to optimise for?  dps? gp/s? dragon-ness? spells/day? early spell access? cosmological power? balance compared to a single-classed fighter as long as possible?  Number of attractive henchmen? Number of specific vulnerabilities?  Some combination of the above?

(If you're just looking for an overview of feats for this kind of warlock, remove the optimization tag)

Comment: Tag removed, my bad

Comment: As far as strongheart vest is concerned he never mentioned it specifically, but I don't want to push my luck. I am also not going to push my luck by trying to cheese Hellfire for more xd6 in Ur-Priest

Comment: For roleplaying purposes, Silver Dragons may be very concerned about their blood in your veins, and the fiendish corruption in your soul.

Comment: @Ruut That is part of the idea behind the character. Always a good time when everyone is mad at you (and you have a habit for dealing with otherworldly entities on a daily basis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At level 6, you seem to be playing to warlock strongly, especially as you don't light the ur-priest rocket until level 10. **Looking closely at the literature, your character, as proposed, is trying to do too many things poorly. Focus either on dragon-fire adept/ur, binder/ur or warlock/binder/hellfire and the feat requirements should flow naturally from your character's intentions.**

Looking at the warlock resources:

- [Warlock Information Compilation by Thinblade](https://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=2997.0)
- [Zombified Warlock Handbook](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?265455-The-Newest-Warlock-Handbook-3-5)

Setting aside any hopes for early entry into anima mage, as you've declared this character to be fairly conservative despite ur priest, you'll be interested in the warlock feats [here](https://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=2997.msg36411#msg36411) and [here](https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=13727972&postcount=2). It seems that you want to be a ranged blaster, there are a number of quite solid psionic feats explicitly precluded by your requirements.

Given that you'll be 2 invocation levels behind (ouch) when you start the character, leadership is always worth picking up just to have someone around to be "useful".

Thematically, Imperious Command is quite flavourful, touching on that whole draconic "fear me." And you'll want to grab [Infernal Adept](https://web.archive.org/web/20200314182345/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frcc/20070613) later on, just for access to the dragon fire adept's invocation list. [This thread (read the whole thing)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029065210/http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3222311) is very well suited to players new to warlock and hellfire warlock.

It's also worth putting binder as your first level and grabbing able learner, to have better access to skills throughout your career. Standard ranged improvement feats (point blank, precise, etc) are also basically necessary if you're going to be ranged.

You assert that:

> Always a good time when everyone is mad at you (and you have a habit for dealing with otherworldly entities on a daily basis).

and

> However fluff wise my character is supposed to have an affinity for dragons so anything there could also work.

Dragonfire-adept / ur-priest / eldritch disciple provides for a much more focused "Dragon dealing with dark forces" than hellfire warlock does, with significant casting capabilities (well worth the ur-priest dip) on top of your dragonbreath. Losing two levels of dragonfire invocations hurts, and you'll have to specifically worship a *dead* deity to provide for chaotic/evil deity worship as well as the ur-priest's "fie on all the gods" things. ). You'll be equivalent to a  "normal" cleric with a 5d6 at-will breath weapon at level 11, and nominally, you'll get 9th level cleric casting 2 levels early. (along with a 7d6 breath weapon). At level 6, you'll need entangling exhalation, iron will, spell focus (grand vizier), and then start down the metamagic feats with extend spell (with an eye towards divine metamagic and persistent spell.) This concept can also be swapped out to normal cleric if your DM understandably says no to you being evil and/or an ur-priest."